# Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server. in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I was try to connect my TFS server using my credentials . But i am getting error  **'Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server.'**

```
 string username = "adminuser";
            string pwd = "mypassword";
            string domain = "http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection";
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, pwd);
            BasicAuthCredential basicAuthCredential = new BasicAuthCredential(networkCredential);
            TfsClientCredentials tfsClientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(basicAuthCredential)
            {
                AllowInteractive = false
            };
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(domain), tfsClientCredentials);
            tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

My tfs didn't have the https. Any alternative to fix it But browser level it is working fine

Comment: Try to use the new API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 4):

The BasicAuthCredential requires https://, I believe, and I wasn't able to access my TFS with https://.  So I found another way to get from NetworkCredential to VssCredentials.

```
string username = "adminuser";
        string pwd = "mypassword";
        string domain = "http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection";

        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, pwd);
        //BasicAuthCredential basicAuthCredential = new BasicAuthCredential(networkCredential);
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential winCred = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(networkCredential);
        VssCredentials vssCred = new VssClientCredentials(winCred);

        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(domain), vssCred);
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
String collectionUri = "http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection";
VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), creds);
```